# How to tile an image

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin to develop an iPhone app.

I have a 1x2 pixel image that I want to tile vertically to form a dotted line in a `xib`, but I don't see any easy way to do this. Xcode doesn't have a content mode for tiling, and although the [UIImage](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage%2fC) class in Xamarin has a [ResizingMode](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage.ResizingMode) property, it's read-only!

Is there a sane way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
UIView tiledView = new UIView();
UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile("your_image.png");
tiledView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(image);
```

On UITableViewCell, the BackgroundColor property is not usable as it is overriden by the UITableView. What I do as a workaround is:

```
private UIView background;

public override void AwakeFromnib() {
    base.AwakeFromNib();
    this.background = new UIView();
    this.background.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
    this.AddSubview(this.background);
}

public override void LayoutSubviews() {
    base.LayoutSubviews();
    this.background.Frame = this.Bounds;
}
```

Just change the BackgroundColor by what you want.

Comment: Hmmm...That's not working for me. For some extra context, my class is derived from UITableCell, so I'm not sure about where would be the appropriate place to place the above code. I tried putting it in the constructor, but that gave me null reference exceptions. So I tried adding it to the `Create` method, but that doesn't seem to work either. There doesn't seem to be an equivalent of `DidAppear` or `DidLoad` for `UITableCell`.

Comment: When the view is instantiated from the Storyboard, you must use the AwakeFromNib() method. The method is called when the view is instantiated and ready to use. Note that on UITableViewCell, you cannot use the background color on the cells. See the edited post for the solution on that kind of views.